# Push image from one field to another

Tags: php

I have one table inventory which includes id (auto-generated), inventory name, image1, image2, image3. And there is only the image name which is going to be stored in table and not the image. Now when I insert data in table I have entered image1 column field, but on adding more image I need to check if image1 is empty store name in image1 else push to image2 and store else if image 2 is full push to image3. How can I achieve the last stage of checking if column is filled or free. The following is code for image and m storing $path in table

```
$filetmp = $_FILES["path1"]["tmp_name"];
        $filename = $_FILES["path1"]["name"];
        $filetype = $_FILES["path1"]["type"];
        $path = "photo/".$filename;
        echo $path;
        move_uploaded_file($filetmp,$logopath);
```

Comment: `if($row['image1'] == null || strlen($row['image1']) == 0)`

Comment: ok got it. Working great.. thanks